# Remote publishing using WP's RetAPI // Issues with HTACCESS

Tags: rest-api

I am accessing a WP site with the WP API BasicAuth plugin installed & activated, and for very basic WP installs the following lines, added to the .HTACCESS files allows perfect GET / POST / PUT requests:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

as:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
```

However, as I have been using iThemes Security, I have a much more verbose .htacces file, as per the below, where only the below 'paragraph seems to disable / dissalow access from a remote site :
Strangest things is that the GET REQUEST works perfectly from POSTMAN:
**

> http://my-wp-website/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

**

A shortened version of the incriminated htacces paragraph:

## Start HackRepair.com Blacklist

```
RewriteEngine on
# Start Abuse Agent Blocking
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Mozilla.*Indy" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Mozilla.*NEWT" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^$" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Maxthon$" [NC,OR]<br/>
```

Many thanks for your help on this 
BR,
JMB

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: HI!<br/>The issue is ..when using iTheme Security, with the above .htaccess paragraphs addesdby the plugin, I can't have any of my previously working GET/POST / PUT RestAPI requests working, to access the data remotely - from a non WP app...-, but I can still run the queries via postman... !
So, I'm wondering what workaround would be possible ?

Comment: Can you just turn off iTheme Security? Whatever the heck that is?

Comment: Hi@JohnDee no can do: it's a security plugin already installera n'y une client..< br/> what I find strange is that the data is accessible via a GET request via POSTMAN...